# JMXConnector failed to connect with ssl keystore

Tags: java, ssl, jmx, keystore

I am trying to connect to an MBean Server on another machine with a ssl keystore but im seeing this error. I have a keystore and truststore on the other server as well. I also noticed that both machines have different java versions. Im not sure if thats the problem or if im missing something.

```
 java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 10.1.7.259; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2432)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
        at com.stop.monitor.giab.JMXListenerClient.connect(JMXListenerClient.java:153)
        at com.stop.monitor.giab.JMXListenerClient.main(JMXListenerClient.java:72)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:248)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:262)
        at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:121)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
        at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.getDefaultClientSocketFactory(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:207)
        at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:117)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
        at sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl_Stub.dirty(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry.makeDirtyCall(DGCClient.java:361)
        at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry.registerRefs(DGCClient.java:303)
        at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient.registerRefs(DGCClient.java:139)
        at sun.rmi.transport.ConnectionInputStream.registerRefs(ConnectionInputStream.java:94)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.releaseInputStream(StreamRemoteCall.java:157)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.done(StreamRemoteCall.java:313)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.done(UnicastRef.java:451)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1957)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1924)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:767)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:733)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770)
        ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was an issue with the firewall. It was because the url used to connect did not specify the second port. So, it just used a random port.

```
    //did not use second port. resulted in using random second port
    String url = "service:jmx:rmi://somehost:9010/jndi/rmi://somehost/jmxrmi";
    final JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);

    //this worked because now we are using 1 port
    String url="service:jmx:rmi://somehost:9010/jndi/rmi://somehost:9010/jmxrmi";
     final JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect` 
>   
> from `TrustManagerFactoryImpl` 
>   
> from `SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager`

Make sure your truststore is valid by doing `keytool -list` *with* password (don't hit return to bypass it). I don't think it's possible to create *trustedcert* entries in a JKS that are incompatible between Java versions (it is in some cases for *privatekey* entries) but to be on the safe side use the `keytool` of the JRE the problematic client uses -- and of course the same file.

Make sure system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` has the filename (if not the default, JRE/lib/security/[jsse]cacerts) and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` has the correct password (always).

Also if the truststore format is not JKS (or PKCS12 in a sufficiently recent Java 8 JRE with `keystore.type.compat` left at its default) specify `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType`. But people who know how to create unusual stores like that don't ask questions like yours.